# how to stub out an IEntityRepository

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

im trying to stub the following line of code in C# using rhino mocks although unsuccessfully.  Any suggestions please?  This is the line that causes the test to fail

```
var header = this.repository.Headers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Id == id);
```

Full details below, many thanks!

**Unit test**

```
  private IRepository _repository;

  [TestInitialize]
  public void SetUp()
  {
    _repository = _mockRepository.Stub<IRepository>();      
    _commandService = new CoreCommandService(_repository);
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void MyTest()
  {
    // Line that doesn't work
    _repository.Stub(x => x.Headers).Return(SomeThing);
  }
```

**implementation**

```
  // The Headers is stubbed although Id is null

  var header = this.repository.Headers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Id == id);

  public interface IRepository
  {
    IEntityRepository<Header> Headers { get; }
  }
```

**UPDATE #1**

```
  public interface IEntityRepository<TEntity> : IQueryable<TEntity>,  IDisposable where TEntity : class
```

**UPDATE #2**

Using the following example

```
  var wrapper = new HeadersWrapper(...);
  _repository.Stub(x => x.Headers).Return(wrapper);
```

Returns the following message when compiling

```
  HeaderWrapper is not assignable to parameter type IEntityRepository<Header>
```

Comment: Does the test fail with an exception? What's `SomeThing`? Is it a collection of `IEntityRepository<Header>` with at least one entry?

Comment: That's what I'm stuck with, not sure what that should :(

Comment: `IEntityRepository<T>` implements some collection type like `IEnumerable<T>`, I assume?

Comment: Please provide more details - what do you mean by "fail" exactly? What was SomeThing when the test failed?

Comment: error is Previous method 'IRepository.get_Headers();' requires a return value or an exception to throw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult.

I think you have two options.

If you can change the return type of `Headers` from `IEntityRepository<T>` to `IQueryable<T>`, you can return a queryable `List<T>` for `Headers`:

```
IList<T> list = new List<Header> { /* Some Header object */ }
IQueryable<T> queryableList = list.AsQueryable();
_repository.Stub(x => x.Headers).Return(queryableList);
```

If you can't change the return type, you need to create a test fake (a new class) that derives from `IEntityRepository<T>`, and wraps a queryable `List<T>`. You will need to implement all the methods that `IEntityRepository<T>` and its interfaces define, but just call the relevant function on the queryable `List<T>`. Then you add a relevant `Header` to the underlying queryable `List<T>` as above and return a new instance of this object to stub `Headers`.

`IQueryable<Header>` Wrapper would look something like this:

```
public class HeadersWrapper : IQueryable<Header>
{
    private readonly IQueryable<Header> _queryableSource;

    public HeadersWrapper(IEnumerable<Header> source)
    {
        _queryableSource = source.AsQueryable();
    }

    public IEnumerator<Header> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _queryableSource.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get { return _queryableSource.Expression; }
    }

    public Type ElementType
    {
        get { return _queryableSource.ElementType; }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get { return _queryableSource.Provider; }
    }
}
```

And you'd use it something like this:

```
var headers = new List<Header>
{
    new Header { Id = "foo" }
};

var wrapper = new HeadersWrapper(headers);

repo.Stub(x => x.Headers).Return(wrapper);
```

And of course, you can exchange `IQueryable<Header>` for `IEntityRepository<Header>` if you want to.

Comment: I'll investigate this and let you know.  Thanks

Comment: struggling to write a fake class tbh that wraps a queryable :(

Comment: Updated with wrapper class

Comment: thanks, I've updated the question with an issue Im experiencing.

Comment: It was an example, using `IQueryable<T>`. I have no idea what your `IEntityRepository<T>` class looks like, so I couldn't use that. To fix your most recent issue, change `HeaderWrapper` to implement `IEntityRepository<Header>`, and stub out any methods that interface adds.